# performing an IF statement based on the weekday name

Tags: vb.net, weekday

I have the following VB.NET code:

```
Dim tomorrow = Now.Date.AddDays(1)
Dim weekdayname = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(tomorrow.DayOfWeek)
If weekdayname = "Thursday" Then
  something(happens)
Else
  something(happens)
End If
```

This doesn't appear to work, i.e. its Thursday today and I want the first thing to happen but it ignores that and goes to the second.

Comment: So what's the value of `weekdayname`?

Comment: If "its Thursday today" and you `AddDays(1)` then the value returned will be "Friday"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say it's thursday today, but your code uses not today but `tomorrow=Date.Now.AddDays(1)`.

Instead of the day-name which depends on  the current culture, i would use the [`DayOfWeek-enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx):

```
Dim today = Date.Today
If today.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Thursday Then
    something(happens) 
Else
    something(happens)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I used your to amend mine and I now have the below.  '        Dim today = Now.Date
        Dim weekdayname = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(today.DayOfWeek)
        If weekdayname = "Thursday" Then
            something(happens)
        Else
            something(happens)
        End If'

Comment: @user2050577: Why do you want to translate the enum value to a localized string before you start to compare it? Have a look at my code, it's much more readable and less error-prone(consider case-sensitivity or different cultures). I don't see the benefit of `GetDayName` at all here. If you need it later you should first use `today.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Thursday` anyway.